# (C#) - store each word between Split in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, split

lets say that was the text in the file. it would remove the colons, and put each word into it's own string in an array. for example:

```
exampleArray[0] = 'hello' 
exampleArray[1] = 'my'
exampleArray[2] = 'name'
exampleArray[3] = 'is'
exampleArray[4] = 'lavi'
```

This is my code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt";
        DialogResult result = ofd.ShowDialog();

        if(result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamReader textfile = new StreamReader(ofd.FileName); 

            string s = textfile.ReadToEnd();

            string[] split = s.Split(':', '\n');

            foreach (string word in split)
                textBox1.Text = word[0].ToString();
                //listBox1.Items.Add(word);


            ofd.Dispose();
        }
```

thanks!

**edit:** What I meant to say is how do I make it so each word is stored in an array so I can access it later with [0], [1], [2], etc.? If Split does that automatically, how do I access each word?

Comment: Can you post a sample of the text file?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Where does the split words need to be stored?

Comment: This question makes no sense. At the point you call `Split`, you in effect made a string array with each item in it's own index. Please clarify the question with your expected input and output.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to. I guess I accidentally erased it. It just had one line saying 'hello:my:name:is:lavi'

Comment: In the end, textBox1 will contain the first char of the last word.

Comment: How do I make it so each word is stored in an array so I can access it later with [0], [1], [2], etc.?  If Split does that automatically, how do I access each word? Sorry, I'm kind of a newbie so if I have this all wrong please correct me

Comment: `String.Split` returns a string array. In your case, just doing `... s.Split(new Char[] {':'});` will do what you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does it automatically (String.split, that is)

```
String str = "hello:my:name:is:lavi";
var words = str.Split(":");
Console.WriteLine(words[1]); //This prints out 'my';
for (int i=0;i<words.Length;i++) {  //This will print out each word on a separate line
    Console.WriteLine(words[i]);
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println`? in c# ?

Comment: Sorry about that, not sure what happened. I thought it was Java while I wrote the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this:

```
foreach (string word in split) textBox1.Text = word.ToString();
```

Comment: that works for outputting 'hello', now just 4 words to go! :P

Comment: foreach (string word in split){
                listBox1.Items.Add(word); }

Answer (score 0):

In response to " What I meant to say is how do I make it so each word is stored in an array so I can access it later with [0], [1], [2], etc.? If Split does that automatically, how do I access each word?"

var myWord = split[0...n]

Answer (score 0):

`string[] exampleArray = str.Split(":");`